# Angular 2- ngOnChanges only for a specific binding

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a possibility to detect changes only for a specific binding property in angular2?

```
 export class Test{
     @Input() a;
     @Input() b;
     constructor() {
         }

     ngOnChanges(){
         //I want that this only called when a changed
         console.log(this.a);
     }
}
```

Comment: it depends how you use `a` and `b`. tell me your output or what `args` shows. I'll let you know how to get an access over `a` or `b`.

Comment: ngOnChanges takes a parameter that  contains what changed, you can filter it to do something only when the one you want has changed, see [docs for OnChanges](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OnChanges-interface.html). You can't make it work only when one has changed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Eric stated, the `ngOnChanges` method will be called on every updates of your `@Input`s.

If you want to detect only the updates of the `@Input` "a" you could use a setter:

```
export class SubComponent {
  @Input()
  set a(a:string) {
    this._a = a;
    console.log('a updated');
  }

  @Input()
  b:any;

  (...)
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/UKyRiq?p=preview.

Comment: One word of caution with a setter:  a component setter should only update the view state of the component and/or its children, and not the application model.  If you were to update the application model, that would break the unidirectional data flow, and parent views might not get updated.
See also [Savkin's blog post](http://victorsavkin.com/post/114168430846/two-phases-of-angular-2-applications), section "How Does Angular Enforce It?" for more about this.

Comment: Also setters do not get called if the binding is an array and array reference does not change if items removed/added. In that case, ngDoCheck comes to the rescue.

Answer (score 1):

Use, (*You will get both variables value in `agrs`*)

```
ngOnChanges(...args: any[]) {  
        console.log('onChange fired');
        console.log('changing', args); // so can access both variables here in args.
        console.log('changing', args[0]); //a's current and previous value if i'm not wrong.
        console.log('changing', args[1]); //b's current and previous value if i'm not wrong.
 }
```

Comment: Instead of `any`, use `ngOnChanges(changes: {[propName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
    console.log(changes.a.currentValue, changes.b.currentValue); }`. There's also a `previousValue` property for each changed input property.

Answer (score 0):

How about using SimpleChanges?

You could try something like this:

> ```
> ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
>     const aChange = changes.a;
>     if((aChange.previousValue && aChange.currentValue) && (aChange.previousValue != aChange.currentValue)){
>         console.log('a changed');
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if ('a' in changes) {
        // do your thing
    }
}
```